# Access delegate methods of UIPageViewController when you've created a protocol

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm using the UIPageViewController and I've made my own protocol like this:

```
@protocol MyDataDelegate <NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>

- (void)recieveData:(NSString *)theData;

@end
```

How can I set the delegate of UIPageViewController to self so I can use those delegate methods? The normal code for this would be `self.delegate = self;` but since I've made another delegate it gives me a warning `"Assigning to 'id<MyDataDelegate>' from incompatible type 'PageScrollViewController *const_strong'"` I want to set this to self so I can access the delegate methods of the UIPageViewController

Comment: Why did you create your own delegate and where do you call recieveData: method from>

Comment: I've created my own delegate to pass data back using a segue.

Comment: You have to declare delegate ivar in UIPageViewController subclass.

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyDataDelegate> delegate;

Comment: Yes I did that like this: @property (nonatomic,weak) id<MyDataDelegate> delegate;

Comment: Does your UIPageViewController conform to MyDataDelegate protocol?

Comment: What do you mean by "conform"?

Comment: Has <MyDataDelegate> in .h file after @interface MyPageViewController : UIPageViewControllerDelegate <MyDataDelegate>

Comment: @interface PageScrollViewController : UIPageViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDelegate>

Comment: and I want to set that UIPageViewControllerDelegate to self

Comment: change weak to assign

Comment: That doesn't matter, it gives the same warning.

Comment: Your subclass eclipses delegate property of UIPageViewController. Give your delegate property some other name: @property (nonatomic,weak) id<MyDataDelegate> myDelegate;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subclass eclipses delegate property of UIPageViewController. Give your delegate property some other name, for instance: @property (nonatomic,weak) id myDelegate;

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your `PageScrollViewController` class to conform to `MyDataDelegate`? You can either do this in the main `@interface` declaration:

```
@interface PageScrollViewController : UIPageViewController <MyDataDelegate>
   // ...
@end
```

Or in the class category in your .m file:

```
@interface PageScrollViewController () <MyDataDelegate>
    // ...
@end
```

Comment: I've done that, instead of using 'delegate' I had to choose another name, that was the problem